# Remove current iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an HTML page that opens an `IFRAME` ... But at some point, after some user interactions with the `IFRAME`, it should close itself. I've tried various commands such as:

```
        var fram = $("IFRAME_NAME");
        fram.parentNode.removeChild(fram);

        this.remove();

        this.style.display='none';

        var frame = parent.frames['IFRAME_NAME'];
        frame.remove();

        frame.html("");

        document.IFRAME_NAME.document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

Thanks.

Comment: you want to remove it from the main document (that contains the Iframe) or from iframe itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering markup like this:

```
<iframe id="myframe" />
```

The following jQuery code will remove it in the host page:

```
$("#myframe").remove();
```

To close the iframe from within iframe itself, define the function in the host page:

```
function closeFrame() {
     $("#myframe").remove();
}
```

Then in the code running in the iframe, call:

```
parent.closeFrame();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (and I've understood your question properly), you can use a code as simple as:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="testframe"></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function () {
       $('#testframe').remove();
    },5000);
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYHx5/